# Using generic methods as an alternative to overloading?

Tags: java, oop, generics

Overloading is fine. But if we consider that we have got
two objects ObjectA and objectB. Both have got "id" and "name" variable. I would like to write a method (in third class), which returns the name of the given object. Writing overloaded function make me repeating the code. Is it a fine practice?
Wouldn't be better to use generic functions instead?

So, I know I can write an overloaded function, sth. like that:

```
public String getInfo(ObjectA o){
    if(o.getId()!=1) return o.name;
    return "";
}
public String getInfo(ObjectB o){
    if(o.getId()!=1) return o.name;
    return "";
}
```

And it works fine.
But both functions are identical! The only difference is the fact, they need an argument of the different type. Because they look the same, isn't it violating the DRY rule?
I tried to write simple generic method, but IDE is marking that.getId and that.name() as an error and recommend casting it as ((ObjectA) that).getId() or ((ObjectB) that).getId(). Haven't I done it in the line"  T that = clazz.cast(o);?
What I am doing wrong?

```
public <T> String getInfo(Class<T> clazz, Object o) {
              T that = clazz.cast(o);
              if (that.getId()!=1) return that.name;

            return "";
        }
```

Generally I would like to know, if my idea is possible. How can i fix my error? And what is more, is it a good idea? Or is it better to simply write overloaded functions?

Comment: A typical solution would be to ensure that both ObjectA and ObjectB implement an interface that declares the hasName and hasId methods.

Comment: Given that `T` is erased to `Object`, the above won't compile, since `Object.getId()` is not an actual method. As others have suggested, you'd need to have a common interface on which `getId` is defined.

Comment: @AndyTurner Type erasure doesn't enter the picture here, it's pure type algebra. The _upper bound_ of `T` is `Object`. The consequences of erasure are only experienced at runtime (and in some degenerate cases at compile time, but only due to the specific twist on erasure in Java).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not expected answers so fast!
Both answers are good, and written at the same time. Truly I do not know which should I mark! :)

Comment: Do keep the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in mind. What if `ObjectB`'s requirements change, and its name gets split up into `firstName` and `lastName`? What will happen to the interface and `ObjectA`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both ideas are bad. Your `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` classes should implement a common interface that defines `getId()` and `getName()` methods.

Then you can get away with a single method:

```
public String getInfo(Interface o){
    if(o.getId()!=1) return o.getName();
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Or just have `getInfo()` be a method on the interface with a default implementation?

Comment: @Kevin I didn't specify where to put the single method ;) but I would most likely not use a default method for a case like this (although it's not clear what the "case" here is). This code seems quite mundane and is easily solved with an "empty" interface.

Answer (score 19):

Your case is a good candidate for Programming to Interface. Create an interface and move common methods.

```
public String getInfo(InterfaceAB in){
    if(in.getId()!=1) return in.getName();
    return "";
}
```